# Pause YouTube video on mouseleave

Tags: javascript, jquery, youtube-api

I have created a function which `inserts an YouTube iframe when user hovers on a div` and then `when mouse leaves the div the video is paused.` Everything works fine but the `video is paused only the first time` and when you click play again and then leave div it dosen't pause. Any ideas? Thanks.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/508oknm7/27/

```
var tag = document.createElement('script'),
    firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];

tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/player_api";
firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);
var player;
$(".video_wrap").on({
    mouseenter: function () {

        player = new YT.Player($(this).children().attr('id'), {
            height: '240',
            width: '320',
            videoId: '-NschES-8e0',
            playerVars: {
            wmode: "transparent",
            controls: 0,
            showinfo: 0,
            rel: 0,
            modestbranding: 1,
            iv_load_policy: 3 //anottations
            },
            events: {
                'onReady': onPlayerReady
            }
        });

        function onPlayerReady(event) {
            player.setVolume(10);
            event.target.playVideo();
        }


    },
    mouseleave: function () {
        player.pauseVideo();

    }
});
```

Comment: Anything in your console? Error when reclicking again?

Comment: Yes: `TypeError: player.pauseVideo is not a function` @JeremyD

Comment: What do you have when you just type player in your console? Maybe you trigger the pauseVideo() call too early. Check how the states transition by printing it/adding breakpoints.

Comment: I get an object. I think there is no longer a mouseleave- since there is no longer a mouseenter - the iframe is completely covering the previous div and therefore you never enter it, so you cant leave it.

Comment: Does the prototype of the object contains anything related to youtube/player? The issue might be that yes, something got messed up with your event handling.

Comment: It's creating a new player on mouseenter each time so it's not stopping the new one on the next mouseleave.

Comment: @intothev01d is correct. You've bound mouseleave to a very specific object, referenced by 'player,' and when mouseenter creates a new player object, mouseleave is no longer bound to it. You could try to do the binding of mouseleave within the mouseenter function, so it rebinds each time you create a new object. Even better would be to trigger the binding in your onPlayerReady function.

Comment: Can you help my by editing my fiddle? Thanks fiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/508oknm7/27/ @jlmcdonald